# Batch - Switch numbers to their letter counterparts and back

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm not exactly sure how to do this, but I am creating a batch file to switch numbers to their letter counterparts and back.

I searched online and I found this from stackoverflow:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "text=This is a test"
set "code=!text!"
set "chars=0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for /l %%N in (1 1 26) do for /f %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do set "code=!code:%%C=%%N !"
echo !text!
echo !code!
pause
```

It works to change the letters to numbers, but I'm trying to change the numbers back to their letter correspondents. (spaces in words are double spaces in numbers)

This seems kind of harder because numbers can be added like `set /a Num+=1`
and letters cannot be added.

Examples of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1 2 3 4 - abcd

19 20 1 3 11 15 22 5 18 6 12 15 23 - stackoverflow

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "text=This is a test"
set "code=%text%"
set "chars=0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for /l %%N in (1 1 26) do for /f %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do set "code=!code:%%C=%%N !"
echo %text%
echo %code%
ECHO ----------------------------------
SET "decode=%code%"
for /l %%N in (26 -1 1) do for /f %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do set "decode=!decode:%%N =%%C!"
echo %text%
echo %code%
ECHO %decode%
GOTO :EOF
```

Since each letter is replaced by a numeric then a space, you need to recognise that `1` means `a`, `11` means `k` and `21` means `u`, so you need to replace the highest numbers first. The number + a space becomes the Nth character in the same string as was used to encode the data.

Please not that `%var%` and `!var!` are the same outside of a loop. Using the `!var!` form outside of a loop may be confusing as it primes the coder to be aware of the difference between the original and changed values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It works but if I input `1 2 3 4 3 2 1`, it outputs `a b c d c b 1` Is that 1 supposed to be there?

Comment: Yes, because it's *not* followed by a space and the encoding scheme is to replace the letter by [a numeric string+a space]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with the batch command powershell.exe. The most difficult issue was dealing with space characters.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content .\cn.ps1
$text = 'This is a test'
$text

$nums = ((($text.ToLower() -replace " ","``").ToCharArray() |
    ForEach-Object { [int]$_ - [int][char]"``" }) -join ' ') -replace ' 0 ','  '
$nums

$letters = ((($nums.Trim()).Split() |
    ForEach-Object { [char]([int]$_ + [int][char]"``") }) -join '') -replace "``"," "
$letters

PS C:\src\t> .\cn.ps1
This is a test
20 8 9 19  9 19  1  20 5 19 20
this is a test
```

It can be written into a batch script.

```
C:\src\t>powershell -NoProfile -File cn.ps1
This is a test
20 8 9 19  9 19  1  20 5 19 20
this is a test
```